# JsonMappingException when calling a RESTful service

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest

I am using Java8 with Spring, Hibernate and JPA.

I have a RESTful service that saves a `Person` object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Person> savePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
    try {
        person = personService.save(person);
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Person p = null;
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(p, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to `merge` a `Person` object:

> 16:02:58,472 WARN 
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver]
>   (default task-11) Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: N/A  at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@7583d44c; line: 29, column: 3] (through
>   reference chain: com.jobs.spring.domain.Person["blockedPersons"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A  at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@7583d44c; line: 29, column: 3] (through
>   reference chain: com.jobs.spring.domain.Person["blockedPersons"])

I guess because it talks about a "`reference chain`", I may have some recursion error. Or for some reason it is struggling to parse the Java into the JSON object.

If anyone can advise, I would appreciate the help.

More info:

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_blocked", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "BLOCK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
    private Set<BlockedPerson> blockedPersons = null;

    ...
}
```

**BlockedPerson.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blocked_person")
@XmlRootElement(name = "blocked_person")
public class BlockedPerson extends AbstractDomain<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "BLOCKED_PER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long blockedPersonId;

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Long getBlockedPersonId() {
        return blockedPersonId;
    }

    public void setBlockedPersonId(Long blockedPersonId) {
        this.blockedPersonId = blockedPersonId;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you would show us Person class.

Comment: Hi CrazySabbath, thanks for the reply. I do have the `Person` class above showing the `@OneToMany` field in question. Would you also like me to show the `getter` and `setters`? (I only started getting this error when this `@OneToMany` field was added).

Comment: My bad, missed bolded text lol. Are you passsing entities directly to your controller? I would avoid that. Can you show Person class declaration? And @RequestBody print? If I were you, I would create other classes, with same fields and extending seriazable. Then I would convert those classes to JPA classes.

Comment: What's more, if you are using spring, you can add RestController annotations to your controller classes and remove @ResponseBody.

Comment: I have updated the code above to show the `Person` class definition. What do you mean by "And @RequestBody print? "? Also, in the Controller, I tried replacing `@ResponseBody` with `@RestController`, but I get: `The annotation @RestController is disallowed for this location`

Comment: You misunderstood me. RestController goes instead of Controller. Then you can remove resposneBody.

Comment: I use `@RestController` at the class level of the Controller already.

Comment: Then you dont need to add @ResponseBody to method signatures. What is  AbstractDomain? You should really seperate JPA classes from controller requests.

Comment: The `Person` object extends `AbstractDomain`.  It just has: `public abstract T getId();`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

The reson for the error above is because I was getting an exception in the setter method on `Person` which was doing the following on a `null` object.

```
this.blockedPersons.clear();
```

Fix:

change:

```
private Set<BlockedPerson> blockedPersons = null;
```

to:

```
private Set<BlockedPerson> blockedPersons = new HashSet<BlockedPerson>();
```